# Mysql query - help getting data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I can handle simple mysql stuff, with single tables normally, but im working on / modifying a script to pull game achievements from a database which has 2 tables.. and this is accessing two tables at once.. so im a little lost. I can understand the line below:

```
SELECT * FROM achievables 
WHERE gameid = '1' 
AND achievementid IN 
(
    SELECT achievementid 
    FROM achievements 
    WHERE userid = '1111'  
    AND gameid = '1'
)
```

This works almost perfect.. however what I want is to also get the DATE field from that second table as well.. I would have thought it was a simple achievementid, date - but that doesnt pull any records, nor does using a SELECT * in the 2nd part..

Comment: @saharsh: I doubt we need that [in-operator] tag and start adding questions to it. If you think otherwise please ask a question on Meta to clear that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to simply use **JOIN** instead of **IN**

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM achievables A 
INNER JOIN achievements B ON A.achievementid = B.achievementid AND A.gameid = B.gameid AND B.userid = '1111' 
WHERE A.gameid = '1';
```

Comment: Yours also gives me the results I was looking for and doesnt end up with repeated columns, which Juergens answer did.. Either way as I responded to Juergen, Im going to be digging into the join tomorrow to try to learn from this.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the tables

```
SELECT a1.*, a2.date
FROM achievables a1
JOIN achievements a2 on a1.achievementid = a2.achievementid
                    and a1.gameid = a2.gameid 
WHERE a1.gameid = '1' 
AND a2.userid = '1111'
```

Comment: Much thanks.. been scratching my head at this for an hour or more trying different combinations.. never did understand that joining but will have to dig into this deeper to understand how it works! thanks!